# My year list doesn't work on BeautifulSoup. Why?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm newbie learning BeautifulSoup. May someone have a look at the following code? I'd like to **scrape** data from a website without any success. I'd like to create a dataframe with the sum of player arrivals per year and with a column of players average age.

dataframe repeating codes:
[img dataframe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlIxQ.png)

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


anos_list = list(range(2005, 2018))

anos_lista = []
valor_contratos_lista = []
idade_média_lista = []

    for ano_lista in anos_list:
        url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/flamengo-rio-de-janeiro/transfers/verein/614/saison_id/'+ str(anos_list) + ''
        page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    tag_list = soup.tfoot.find_all('td')
    valor = (tag_list[0].string)
    idade = (tag_list[1].string)
    ano = ano_lista 

    valor_contratos_lista.append(valor)
    idade_media_lista.append(idade)
    anos_lista.append(ano)


flamengo_df = pd.DataFrame({'Ano': ano_lista,
         'Despesa com contratações':valor_contratos_lista,
                        'Média de idade': idade_média_lista
                       })
flamengo_df.to_csv('flamengo.csv', encoding = 'utf-8')`
```

Comment: What are you trying to take from the website?

Comment: you need to describe what isn't working and what the expected result should be.

Comment: Id like to create a dataframe with sum of player arrivals per year and with a column of players average age.

Comment: the indentation of your code it is wrong, if is this of post. check this, or correct the post.

Comment: You have a typo: `url = ... + str(ano_lista) + ''`. You should be appending the iterator, not the entire `anos_lista`

Comment: Sorry, I didnt get. Im a total beginner hehehe

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

**Using Beautiful Soup + Regex:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import numpy as np

# Set min and max years as variables
min_year = 2005
max_year = 2019
year_range = list(range(min_year, 2019+1))
base_url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/flamengo-rio-de-janeiro/transfers/verein/614/saison_id/'

# Begin iterating
records = []
for year in year_range:

    url = base_url+str(year)

    # get the page
    page = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

    # I used the class of "responsive table"
    tables = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'responsive-table'})
    rows = tables[0].find_all('tr')
    cells = [row.find_all('td', {'class':'zentriert'}) for row in rows]

    # get variable names:
    variables = [x.text for x in rows[0].find_all('th')]
    variables_values = {x:[] for x in variables}
    # get values
    for row in rows:
        values = [' '.join(x.text.split()) for x in row.find_all('td')]
        values = [x for x in values if x!='']

        if len(variables)< len(values):
            values.pop(4)
            values.pop(2)  
        for k,v in zip(variables_values.keys(), values):
            variables_values[k].append(v)

    num_pattern = re.compile('[0-9,]+')
    to_float = lambda x: float(x) if x!='' else np.NAN
    get_nums = lambda x: to_float(''.join(num_pattern.findall(x)).replace(',','.'))

    # Add values to an individual record
    rec = {
        'Url':url,
        'Year':year,
        'Total Transfers':len(variables_values['Player']),
        'Avg Age': np.mean([int(x) for x in variables_values['Age']]),
        'Avg Cost': np.nanmean([get_nums(x) for x in variables_values['Fee'] if ('loan' not in x)]),
        'Total Cost': np.nansum([get_nums(x) for x in variables_values['Fee'] if ('loan' not in x)]),
    }

    # Store record
    records.append(rec)
```

**Thereafter, initialize dataframe:**
*Of note, some of the numbers represent millions and would need to be adjusted for.*

```
import pandas as pd

# Drop the URL
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['Year','Total Transfers','Avg Age','Avg Cost','Total Cost'])

    Year  Total Transfers    Avg Age    Avg Cost  Total Cost
0   2005               26  22.038462    2.000000        2.00
1   2006               32  23.906250  240.660000     1203.30
2   2007               37  22.837838  462.750000     1851.00
3   2008               41  22.926829  217.750000      871.00
4   2009               31  23.419355  175.000000      350.00
5   2010               46  23.239130  225.763333     1354.58
6   2011               47  23.042553  340.600000     1703.00
7   2012               45  24.133333  345.820000     1037.46
8   2013               36  24.166667  207.166667      621.50
9   2014               37  24.189189  111.700000      335.10
10  2015               49  23.530612  413.312000     2066.56
11  2016               41  23.341463  241.500000      966.00
12  2017               31  24.000000  101.433333      304.30
13  2018               18  25.388889  123.055000      738.33
14  2019               10  25.300000         NaN        0.00
```

Comment: Modified answer to do desired operation. _I was pulling from a diff table._

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but regex library is too much for me for a while.

Comment: It takes time to learn. Keep at it, you'll be able to master it sooner than later.